# Flutter run stuck at Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)"

Tags: flutter, android-sdk-build-tools

I have just set up flutter development environment and after creating first app, on flutter run, debug console is stuck at

```
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)".
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flutter is trying to install Android SDK build tools. This will be installed even if you already have a different version of the SDK. Since the SDK is quite large, it may take some time to download and unpack

Answer (score 0):

In my case it caused by McAfee. After turning off the virus scan and firewall functions everything went well.